# How to set object properties to null and blank array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

So I have this object for example:

```
family_background: {
      children: [],
      spouse_surname: null,
      spouse_first_name: null,
      spouse_first_name: null,
      spouse_middle_name: null,
      spouse_occupation: null,
      spouse_employer: null,
      // so forth and so on
}
```

The way I set the values to null is like this:

```
  for (var key in family_background) {
    family_background[key] = null;
  }
```

But I have a property that is equal to an array and by doing the loop, it would set the property to null also instead of a blank array.

How can I fix this? Am I missing something?

Comment: So you want to set the property to empty array if it is an array and null otherwise?

Comment: @Saravana yes that's it

Comment: What I don't understand is how did you think that your solution should set it to a blank array. "Am I missing something?" :D please try to use google first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the value is an `instanceof Array`, and if so, set it to an empty array.

```
for (var key in family_background) {
    family_background[key] = family_background[key] instanceof Array
        ? []
        : null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.isArray` to check if your property is an array before you set the values:

```
for (var key in family_background) {
    family_background[key] = Array.isArray(family_background[key]) ? [] : null;
}
```

MDN documentation for `Array.isArray`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

Comment: Thank you for this.